# Visual Studio Extensibility + WPF + Loading Controls in seperate appdomain

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, appdomain, vs-extensibility

My scenario is as follows:

I have a visual studio 10 vspackage project with a tool window in it. This tool window has a UI that lets you create a configuration xml file (so imagine the toolwindow on one side and the standard VS xml editor on the other). The xml file is actually the serialization output of a class (Imagine a List of ISomething) and the types it contains are discovered by the UI using reflection. The UI also allows the user to edit the properties of each instance (via propertygrid) before serializing the output to the xml.

Everything is fine but I had planned on allowing the tool box to discover plugins in the currently running VS project. This means that everytime the project is built the UI should load the project's output and find new plugins / update existing ones. If I do this without having a way of unloading the previously built assemblies I am gonna end up with a mess after a few builds.

I have spent the better part of the day searching for a solution and have run into a lot of things but not quite I am looking for.

The solution I think would be the easiest to implement (from my side) is to be able to host the UI (WPF control) on a different appDomain which will be teared down everytime the project is built, but at this point I am open to any solutions / suggestions any of you guys might offer.

Thanks in advance,
John